# Simple Form I18n labels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, simple-form

Hi everyone in my app I build a search box. It looks like this:

```
= simple_form_for :cars, {url: cars_path, method: :get} do |f|
  = f.input :handover_location, collection: Location.all.map{|hl| [hl.name, hl.id]}
  = f.input :return_location, collection: Location.all.map{|rl| [rl.name, rl.id]}
  = f.input :car_class, collection: CarClass.all.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, include_blank: true
  = f.submit
```

And now i don't know how to translate this labels with I18n. How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check the simple-form documentation regarding i18n: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#i18n

It is pretty well described, and goes into great detail.

So for instance (from the documentation) :

```
en:
  simple_form:
    labels:
      defaults:
        username: 'User name'
        password: 'Password'
        new:
          username: 'Choose a user name'
    hints:
      defaults:
        username: 'User name to sign in.'
        password: 'No special characters, please.'
    placeholders:
      defaults:
        username: 'Your username'
        password: '****'
```

This specifies the defaults for labels.
You should check the documentation, because there are a lot more options.

Secondly, you can also do it explicitly, like so

```
= f.input :car, label: I18n.t('my_car_label'), prompt: I18n.t('my-car-prompt'), placeholder: I18n.t('my-placeholder')
```

Comment: I think this is the better answer due to the focus on the simple form gem.

Comment: Simple-form documentation is not "well described" just because examples  contains only second part - dictionary, and there is no form example for that dictionary. From your answer I can not understand the way "simple_form_for" tag should be looks like, either you did not explained how the dictionary should looks like for the form in the question.

Comment: It is not so hard though, and the documentation does explain it well, why should I repeat it? Anyway, in short you do not adapt anything in the form, and in the translation you use the model-name, and then deeper you write the attribute name, it seems obvious to me. Do you need a more specific example?

Answer (score 3):

First off, I'd begin by perusing the [docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html), particularly part 3. For forms based on active record models, Rails has some custom built-in support (see part 4.6 of the docs). For instance, to translate your `Car` model name to something other than "Car", you could do this:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      car:
        one: Automobile
        other: Automobiles
```

(Substitute for your language of choice to support I18n.)

However, to use I18n in general, you'd call the `translate` method Rails provides, abbreviated by `t`. Example:

```
= simple_form_for :cars, {url: cars_path, method: :get} do |f|
  ..
  = f.label t('forms.car_class')
  = f.input :car_class, collection: CarClass.all.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, include_blank: true
  ..
  = f.submit 

# config/locales/en.yml

en:
  forms:
    car_class: 'Automobile'
```

Which would render the label with the text: 'Automobile'.